# Обновление данных в одном конкретном столбце QTableView

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2, qtableview

Имеется tableview, данные туда подгружаются из заранее отформатированного txt файла с помощью csv.reader и распределяются на столбцы и строки так, как мне требуется, с этим я справился.

Осталась одна проблема - необходимо сделать один столбец (последний) обновляемым.

В общем имеется источник данных - информация с регистров slave устройства(modbus), и эти данные должны динамически обновляться в последнем столбце и при этом, чтобы остальные столбцы оставались неизменными.

В качестве модели использую QtGui.QStandardItemModel.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете это сделать при помощи метода [QStandartItemModel.setItem](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QStandardItemModel.html#PySide2.QtGui.PySide2.QtGui.QStandardItemModel.setItem) и сигнала [QStandartItemModel.itemChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QStandardItemModel.html#PySide2.QtGui.PySide2.QtGui.QStandardItemModel.itemChanged).

Допустим, вот так:

```
# Получили новые данные для ячейки
newItem = QStandartItem()
newItem.setText(<Какое-то новое значение>)
lastColIdx = self.model.columnCount() -1
self.model.setItem(<индекс строки таблицы>, lastColIdx, newItem)

# Теперь надо сообщить всем, что данные в модели изменились
self.model.itemChanged.emit(newItem)
```